# git svn dcommit fail

Tags: git, dcommit

when I do git svn dcommit, it report error like below:

```
git svn dcommit
Committing to http://192.168.33.203/svn/repos/mt6577/platform/branches/vendor-ALPS.ICS2.6577.SP.V1_HUAQIN77_CU_ICS ...
summit merge conflict: file or directory “mediatek/platform/mt6577/external/meta/sgx” is out of date；please update: resource out of date; try updating at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 579
```

My operations:

1. do three commits(commit34,commit35,commit36) in local
2. git svn dcommit these three commits to svn
3. amend commit34,commit35 by rebase command
4. git svn dcommit , then report above error.

How to handle the error, thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, **never rebase commits that you have pushed back to repository** when using git. Although you are working with git-svn,  `rebase` these commits is not a good idea. Why? Because `rebase` alters the commit history,  this is ok when you just work in local.

In your case, you can run `git svn fetch/rebase` and resolve any conflict, then `dcommit` it back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it seems no 'git svn update' command, any other command instead ?

Comment: when I input 'git svn fetch',it report error: REPORT request failde on 'svn/ngrm/!svn/vcc/default'; when I input 'git svn rebase', it report some conflict different from my modification. I don't know what is wrong. Now I do another 'git svn clone' to redo my job by new commit, hope it will be OK.

Comment: I redo my job after hard reset. Later I won't do rebase after doing remote push. Thanks a lot .